# Is it possible to create 2-side bar chart using Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

Is it possible to create something like that using Matplotlib(without gradient colors or/and numbers above every bar) All I found was how to lay charts on top of each other.[image: 2-side bar chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the reverse histogram using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`, negative weights can be put to the values using the parameter `weigths`.

Minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.random.random(100)
x2 = np.random.random(100)

plt.hist(x1, facecolor='teal', edgecolor='white', range=(0, 1))
plt.hist(x2, fc='tomato', ec='white', weights=np.full(len(x2), -1), range=(0, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image]